# How to draw a pattern of circles with a pattern of triangle inside using c++

Tags: c++

I need to put this triangle pattern inside a circle of stars. I have two different codes for it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nooflines=10, counter, blanks=1;
    int line=10;

     cout<<endl;
     
    for(counter=1; counter<=line; counter++){
        for(int count=1; count<=nooflines; count++){
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for(int count=1; count<=blanks; count++){
            cout<<" *";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        blanks++;
        nooflines--;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I need to put the triangle of stars inside a circle of stars. I need help with this. If you could help me please try also explaining using a comment. Thank you!`your text`

Comment: Unfortunately, *standard* C++ has no facilities for drawing (except for ASCII art).  You're going to need a graphics library or a windowing framework, or use an OS API.

Comment: Search the internet for "inscribed triangle in circle" to get some idea of how to calculate the lines of the triangle inside the circle.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that, what you have to do is deciding output letter(star or space) for each position.

So, for example, code will become as:

```cpp
//This function returns space or star
char DecideOutputCharAt( int x, int y )
{  /*You have to compensate here*/  }

//
int main()
{
    const int OutputWidth = 40;
    const int OutputHeight = 30;
    for( int y=0; y<OutputHeight; ++y )
    {
        for( int x=0; x<OutputWidth; ++x )
        {
            std::cout << DecideOutputCharAt(x,y);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what kind of output result is really requested, but if give some example, it may be as:

```cpp
bool IsOnCircle( double x, double y )
{
    static const double Cx=20;
    static const double Cy=15;
    static const double R = 13;

    double dx = x - Cx;
    double dy = y - Cy;
    double err = fabs( R - sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) );
    return err <= 0.5;
}

bool IsInTriangle( double x, double y )
{
    static const double Px[] = {  9, 19, 23 };
    static const double Py[] = { 13,  5, 20 };

    for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
    {
        int k = (i+1)%3;
        double xx = x - Px[i];
        double yy = y - Py[i];
        double tx = Px[k] - Px[i];
        double ty = Py[k] - Py[i];
        if( xx*ty - yy*tx > 0 )return false;
    }
    return true;
}

char DecideOutputCharAt( int x, int y )
{
    return ( IsOnCircle(x,y) || IsInTriangle(x,y) )  ?  '*'  :  ' ';
}
```

Output of this exmaple becomes as below.
Here, underbar letter is employed instead of space (to visualize).

As you can see, some part is not beautiful.
If you want more good result, employ some better rasterize algorithm etc.

```
________________________________________
________________________________________
_________________*******________________
______________***_______***_____________
_____________**___________**____________
___________**______*________**__________
__________**______**_________**_________
__________*______***__________*_________
_________*______****___________*________
________**____*******__________**_______
________*____********___________*_______
________*___*********___________*_______
_______*___**********____________*______
_______*_*************___________*______
_______*___***********___________*______
_______*_____*********___________*______
_______*_______*******___________*______
_______*_________******__________*______
_______*___________****__________*______
________*____________**_________*_______
________*______________*________*_______
________**_____________________**_______
_________*_____________________*________
__________*___________________*_________
__________**_________________**_________
___________**_______________**__________
_____________**___________**____________
______________***_______***_____________
_________________*******________________
________________________________________
```